# A racing anime or cartoon similar to Scan2Go with a yellow bat that is possessed by the ghost of the former champion

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

It's an anime in a world similar to *Scan2Go* or the world of *Beyblade* with little cars instead of Beyblade.

The story starts with a kid who finds the race car of the former champion in a junkyard. When he picks up the car, the ghost of the former champion who died tries to take over the MC's body but fails and ends up possessing a yellow bat. From there, they work together to stop the current champion who is an evil guy who killed the former champion. The main car is a red car with black stripes like a tiger.

I watched this anime many times in my childhood and have been trying to find this anime for a long time, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Beompeoking Jaepeo](https://myanimelist.net/anime/19547/Beompeoking_Jaepeo)***, AKA *Bumper King Zapper* (2004)...?

> Bumper King Zapper is a 3D animation series about bumper car battles of the future.

This appears to be a South Korean animation, but unfortunately I can't find much information about the plot online. Some episodes have been uploaded to YouTube, but the audio is in Korean with no subtitles, and YouTube's auto-generated subtitles aren't much help. My description of the first episode below is based entirely on my interpretation of the visuals, since I can't follow any of the dialogue.

The first episode begins in a large arena, where two competitors named Asura and Zapper are driving battle vehicles around circular tracks and collecting icons of some sort. Zapper's car is red with black markings on it, while Asura's car is purple. The two cars then face off in a head-to-head battle, and Asura projects ethereal tendrils that latch onto Zapper through his car. Asura ultimately wins the battle and Zapper's car explodes.

The scene then cuts to a young boy, who suddenly wakes up in his bedroom, apparently having dreamed all this. Later, the boy is in what looks like a junkyard, accompanied by a small yellow creature with purple, batwing-like ears. While looking around, the boy notices a remote controlled car that looks like the one Zapper was driving in the opening scene, and after picking it up, turns around to see Zapper standing a few feet away from him.

They talk for a bit, before the boy notices that Zapper is intangible and starts running away in fear. Zapper then takes on a more spectral appearance and telekinetically moves large objects in front of the boy, blocking his exit. Zapper has the boy cornered, and lunges towards him, but then the small yellow creature gets in the way, and Zapper ends up inside it, apparently possessing it.

You can view the scene where the boy finds the remote controlled car at around the 15:29 mark in the video below.

Comment: There's also an [archive of the official website](https://web.archive.org/web/20071110222654/https://daewonmedia.com/en/contents/1/12_view.asp?idx=4&page=1) which has a synopsis (written in unidiomatic English, unfortunately).